# Migrate MySQL from Mamp to Default MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, macos, mamp

I found OSX MySQL only reachable when I using MAMP in port 8889 for some reason, also I can not access them via MySQL CLI also, why? I've tried to add new IP tables and even stop the firewalls, but it still not work, CLI is a bit useless now. We already backup all the databases but don't know what is the safest steps to replace the current MySQl (MAMP) with pure MySQL or MariaDB and it's default server without reinstalling the OSX. Thanks.